# Associate a specific objects from the dependent model for each row of another model in Django

Tags: django

I have these models:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Milestone(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='milestones', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

...and example data:

```
{name: 'SpaceY', milestones: 
    [{id:1, project: 1, description: '1st milestone description',completed: False}, 
     {id: 2, project: 1, description: '2nd description',completed: False}]}, 

{name: 'ProjectX', milestones: 
    [{id:3, project: 2, description: 'ProjectX 1st Desc',completed: True}, 
     {id: 4, project: 2, description: 'one more description',completed: False}]}
```

... and I need output like this:

```
{name: 'SpaceY', milestone: 
    {id:1, project: 1, description: '1st milestone description', completed: False}}, 

{name: 'ProjectX', milestone: 
     {id: 4, project: 2, description: 'one more description', completed: False}}
```

i.e. I want only one not completed milestone with the smallest id for every Project. And no Project if all milestones were completed.

I've tried to use prefetch_related and other things but the best I got was many duplicated Projects.

May it be solved with Django ORM or I need dive into raw sql?

Comment: have you tried using .distinct()? 
also, what queries have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the following query works for me

```
queryset = Milestone.objects.filter(completed=False).order_by('project_id','id').distinct('project_id')
```